# Delphi example of Rest Client using XML format

Tags: xml, rest, delphi

I would like to know what Delphi components to use in order to POST , GET , UPDATE etc using a Rest Client to access an API using XML.  There are TRestClient and other Delphi components but it seems that work only with JSON and XML is not supported.

Thank you

Comment: Can you automate `MSXML2.XMLHttpRequest.6.0` from Delphi? It allows you to make HTTP POST request, sending an `MSXML2.DomDocument.6.0` as the response body. GET and POST can receive/parse the response as XML.

Comment: There are a lot of HTTP/HTTPS components for Delphi (I recommend [ICS](http://wiki.overbyte.be) or Indy). The details of the required depends on the API specification. And you said nothing about it.